# What is the meaning of DN and DRVAL2 categorie?

Tags: qgis, terminology

I try to find the meaning of the categories DN and DRVAL2 when I used them in the command:

```
lrenderer = new QgsCategorizedSymbolRendererV2("DRVAL2" , Categrories );
```

Is there any tutorial or documentation about all of this kind of parameter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little googling : http://www.caris.com/s-57/attribut/drval2.htm

DRVAL2 => 'The maximum (deepest) value of a depth range'

DN is generally => Digital Number